# Для чего нужны Clean Project, Rebuild Project, Invalidate Cashes / Restart?

Tags: android-studio

Для чего нужны пункты меню «Clean Project», «Rebuild Project», «Invalidate Cashes / Restart»? Как ими грамотно пользоваться?

Comment: Вот на английском языке Обсуждение такого же Вопроса и развернутые (и многократно одобренные) ответы на него: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347184/difference-and-when-to-use-getapplication-getapplicationcontext-getbasecon/10347346#10347346

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Clean Project` как следует из названия - чистит его, удаляя временные файлы сборки. Бывает полезно при разных глюках, когда вы меняете что-то в коде/ресурсах но не видите изменений при перезапуске, т.к. старая версия файла осталась во временной папке. Также помогает при смене версии либы - в последнем `gradle` есть баг с дублирующимися зависимостями из-за этого, который лечится как раз очисткой проекта.
2. `Rebuild Project` - проде как очистка + сборка проекта. Т.е. должно очистить временные файлы и собрать проект заново, все файлы заново создав. Лично мне за годы практики нужна была всего 2 раза.
3. `Invalidate Cashes / Restart` - самое радикальное лекарство от багов студии. Следует использовать, если у вас что-то не работает и `Clean Project` не помогает. Эта операция чистит временные файлы уже самой студии. Бывают ситуации, когда только эта кнопка помогает.

Comment: Спасибо, друг! Плюс я поставил. Но принять ответ окончательно пока не могу,... подожду, хотелось бы еще подробней!

Comment: @YuriK, ну... Подождать, конечно, можно, но я сомневаюсь, что что-то совсем подробное кому-то получится написать) Обычно этих сведений достаточно)

Comment: 2 раза? Rebuild же нужно всегда использовать когда Dagger подключаешь?

Comment: @Cypher, ну так его один раз подключил и всё. Т.е. да, ему надо сгенерить `AppComponent`, но это вполне себе происходит при простом запуске `run`. Лишний раз ждать пока все пересоберётся просто ради генерирования одного файла лично я не вижу смысла)